# SQL Server 2008: No 'release savepoint' for current transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using a PHP database abstraction layer to work with both MySQL and SQL Server. MySQL has a 'release savepoint' statement which SQL Server does not support, and I can't find a comparable statement within T-SQL to use in its stead. Does anybody know of a way around this, or can the lack of functionality be safely ignored?

I'd appreciate any insight!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you do not need to do any operation to release a savepoint. Savepoints are 'released' automatically at the final transaction commit or rollback, you don't need to manage them intermediately.

Comment: Cool, that's what I'd hoped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about MySQL but it sounds a bit like using

```
Save Transaction <Name> and Rollback Transaction <Name>
```

to partially rollback a transaction to a named point. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx)

Comment: Those statements map to MySQL's SAVEPOINT <NAME> and ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT <NAME>; the purpose of RELEASE is to delete a savepoint without committing or rolling back at at all. From the MySQL Manual:

"The RELEASE SAVEPOINT statement removes the named savepoint from the set of savepoints of the current transaction. No commit or rollback occurs. It is an error if the savepoint does not exist."

I don't think those statements provide that functionality?

Comment: I understand now, I've not come across anything to clear a transaction marker. I would guess you can probably ignore them

Comment: This is incorrect. ROLLBACK TRANSACTION, with or without a name, rolls back to the outermost transaction. You can prove this with @@TRANCOUNT - nest a second transaction, check @@TRANCOUNT (will be 2), then rollback the "inner" nested one. @@TRANCOUNT will now be zero, Also https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI standard syntax is SAVEPOINT , ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT , and RELEASE SAVEPOINT . Oracle, DB/2, MySQL, Postgres, Sybase, Informix, Interbase, and Firebird all use that same, standard, syntax. SQL Server is the oddball with a different syntax and no "release".

As Remus Rusanu said, though, it's not strictly required, but could help the database manage internal resources better if it knew that the savepoint was no longer necessary (it certainly helps on multigenerational architectures like Oracle, Interbase and Firebird).